# How to use a field as an entity's property

Tags: entities

My module provides its own entity. I need my entity to have a link field with multiple values. The module link is suitable for this. At install hook, I create a field and a field instance of link type.

But at entity's fields management page, this field looks like a regular filed, that can be deleted by user. But I need this field to be a hard part of my entity, as a property. How can I make this?

This case is not exactly about link field, but generally of creating entity's properties of field types.

Comment: You can make the field config itself un-editable by setting `'locked' => TRUE` in the definition - I don't think there's anything specific for instances though. As far as I know there isn't a way to use a field widget on a property, so you'd probably need to reproduce the validation logic from Link manually

Comment: I found an article https://drupal.org/node/1156554 But I cant understand if it is connected with my question.

Comment: I don't think it is, that's about describing property data types to the entity API module (so they can be used properly in an `EntityMetadataWrapper` for example)